Equations of motion for constant acceleration
I read that the equations of motion for a constant acceleration can be represented in a scalar form as well as a vector form, but what's the need to do them in vector form what extra can we do by representing them in vector form?

You can analyse both 1-D and 2-D motions with the help of vector form. Also, vector form gives you a lot of information of the directions of motion. Scalar form is simply valid for just 1-D motions otherwise it's difficult to apply it in 2-D.

You can analyze multiple things, each moving with constant acceleration in different directions. This can be done using the vector form, and not the 1D form.

so, basically the vector form allows us to analyze 2 dimensional motion as it is without breaking it up onto 1 dimensional motions? Am I right?
